# Rails 6 app ignores custom CSS file. How do I add it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-6, sprockets, webpacker

I am trying to add a custom CSS file to an existing Rails 6 app.

The app has installed (among other) these gems (`Gemfile`):

```
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'sassc-rails'
...
```

In `Gemfile.lock`, I can see there also sprockets-related gems, like:

```
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

and so on.

I tried to add my custom JS file to `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss` and I defined to this file my own CSS. In this directory was already an `application.scss` with this content:

```
 /*
 * require jquery-ui
 * require_tree .
 * require_self
 */
 @import 'custom'; // I added this line to reflect the new file
```

If I simply copy the CSS data from `custom.scss` and paste it to `application.scss`, it doesn't work either - it looks like even `application.scss` is not activated somehow.

Then, in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`, there's this content:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link application.scss
//= link vendor/slick.min.js
```

Here, I tried to add `//= link custom.scss`, but it didn't help.

And this is the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.0.0-beta.5",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "el-transition": "^0.0.7",
    "google-maps": "^4.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

In `application.html.haml`, this is how is loaded the main CSS:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

If I try to add

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom'
```

I get this error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Site#home
custom.css
```

How do I properly define and load my custom CSS styles? I am not able to find the proper setup.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add `//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css` into your `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Answer (score 0):

I used this guide to add bootstrap as well as custom styling
https://dev.to/shahershamroukh/add-bootstrap-and-fontawesome-to-your-ruby-on-rails-6-application-3fm7